# Adjust weight for menu items in different languages

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

My site will be in English and Arabic. English reads from left to right and Arabic from right to left. Drupal 8 works great with this if you enable all 4 multilingual extentions.

The only problem I have is that I translated the main menu, but I can't find how I can add a different weight to the separate menu items, this since I want the menu to be mirrored on Arabic.

If you go to the separate menu items you can add a weight but above it it is written: Weight (all languages)

How can I adjust the weight per language per item?

**UPDATE**: the answer by *Owais Alam* does not handle the adjustment of menu-items-weight per language in Drupal 8

Answer (score 2):

With Drupal 7 core alone, user-defined menu items are not translatable. The Menu translation module, part of the Internationalization (i18n) package, allows users to select a translation mode for each menu (Figure 1).

The following modes are available:

1. No Multilingual Options
2. Translate and Localize
3. Fixed Language

[image]

**Translate and Localize Menus**

For most use cases, and especially if the structure of your menus is consistent across languages, Translate and Localize is the preferred method of translating menus. You can create one menu for all languages, and translate or localize each menu item. There are two ways that menu items will be translated:

- You can set a language when creating a custom menu item so that the
  menu item will only show up for that language (Figure 1). Menu items
  that link to nodes in a particular language will be treated this way.
- You can localize other custom menu items without a language (for
  example, menu items linking to Views pages). Use the Translate tab to
  translate the menu item title and description (Figure 2). Translators
  can also use the 'Translate interface' pages to translate these menu
  items (Figure 3).

[image]

**Figure 2**

[image]

**Figure 3**

**Fixed Language Menus**

If you choose Fixed Language, you'll have to set up a separate menu in each language. This could become tedious if have a lot of languages enabled on your site, but is useful if the content or menu structure is different for each language.

**Menu Items Linked to Nodes**

Useful modules:

- For Entity translation use entity_translation_i18n_menu submodule of
  [Entity translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation).
- For content translation use [Menu translation - Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation).

A menu item linked to a node will be displayed only when the node language matches the page language. This is due to how the menu system works and the 'Language selection' feature in i18n. Therefore, to get translated menus items that link to nodes, you first need translated content: see Translating content to different languages.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Even though this in no way answer my question. I am working with Drupal 8 (as is written) and this is for 7. Furthermore it does not cover the weight of menu-items in any way. Do you have any idea how to adjust the weight per language in Drupal 8 with translation core modules enabled?

Comment: ok hope this will help you https://www.drupal.org/node/2415945

Comment: @OwaisAlam You should let others know the Drupal version in your question, otherwise, it will ruins others' effort.

Comment: @JimmyKo i have mentioned Drupal 7. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @OwaisAlam please add it in tag as well :)

Comment: Could I ask you to delete the anwser since it is totally of topic and might prevent people who actually know how to change the weight per language to anwser especially since someone up voted this anwser.

Comment: @WillyBurb : even though I agree that this answer is about D7 (while your question is, from the beginning, about D8), I do not think that "this" answer will stop anybody, who does have a D8 answer for you, to post another D8-related attempt to answer your question. If I was you, I'd edit my own question by adding a note to the end of it like "*Note*: the answer from [Owais Alam](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/66189/owais-alam) does not help (it's about D7, my question is about D8)". As a variation, just add that as an extra comment below your question. Good luck!